# Free website/software for recording screen with audio from microphone

Tags: windows-10, screen-recording, audio-recording

I want to record my screen together with my voice via a microphone.
How can I do that in Windows 10?

Actually I want to teach/demonstrate use of a programming software through screen recording with my voice in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 can do this by itself. When in the program, press Win+G to open the game bar / panel. There you can start a screen recording, and activate your microphone during the recording.

[image: Windows 10 Game panel]